# How to pass values calculated by a controller function as arguments to a directive from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Angular Newbie Question:

I would like to run a function `myFunc` within my AngularJS controller (`myController`) that calculates some values `aB` and `aC`.

I then want to have my HTML send those calculated values to a directive `myDirective` as arguments. How can I do it? I assumed attaching those values to the scope would work well.

The code below doesn't work.

The first problem I have is that I don't know when and how should I call `myFunc`. 
When it comes to line #7 in the HTML, I want `myFunc` to already have been run. How do I do that?

My second (and bigger) problem is that even when the values of `aB` and `aC` are calculated by `myFunc`, attached to the scope and passed in through the HTML as arguments to `myDirective`, the `console.log` lines #21 & #22 in that directive still report them as `undefined`. Why? The strange thing is they get rendered on the screen anyway by the `template: 'aB={{aB}} aC={{aC}}'`. How can that even happen??

This behavior is made even more confusing because when I send in literal values as arguments to `myDirective` in line #6 of the HTML, it works perfectly. The `console.log` lines #21 & #22 report them correctly. Why the difference?

My HTML:

```
 1  <body ng-app="myApp">
 2    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 3      <div ng-view></div>
 4      <ul>
 5        <li>{{1+1}}</li>
 6        <li><my-directive a-b="null" a-c="'Goodbye'"></my-directive></li>
 7        <li><my-directive a-b="arguments.scopeAB" a-c="arguments.scopeAC"></my-directive>  </li>  
 8      </ul>
 9    </div>
10  </body>
```

My JavaScript:

```
11  myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
12  myApp.directive('myDirective',function(){
13      return {
14          restrict:'E',
15          scope: {
16              aB: '=',
17              aC: '='
18          },
19          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
20              console.log('scope = ', scope);
21              console.log('scope.aB = ', scope.aB);
22              console.log('scope.aC = ', scope.aC);
23          },
24          template: 'aB={{aB}} aC={{aC}}'
25      };
26  });
27  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
28      var self = this;
29
30        self.myFunc = function(response) {
31          scope.arguments.scopeAB = 'Hello';
32          scope.arguments.scopeAC = 'World';
33        }
34      }
35  );
36
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saqibali75/0p1Lbg3r/4/)

Comment: i dont understand why you dont want to set variables directly in controller... but you can always use $timeout to set variables after angular finish its work

Comment: Petr, I would be happy to do that! Can you show me how I can do that so that in line #7 of the HTML I can then pass those variables into `my-directive`.

Comment: by the way, it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  even if that `'$viewContentLoaded'` even triggered (which requires `ngRoute`, btw), the code within would error since `MyCtrl` doesn't have access to the directive's `scope` properties (they are isolated).

Comment: Ok. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish: Have a controller function that sets some values on the scope. And then in the HTML send those values to  `my-directive` as arguments. It sounds simple, but I'm finding it frustratingly difficult.

Comment: That last explanation is very ambigous also

Comment: Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/MFLpW8NJSiCzPWLg2L4c?p=preview : Change the directive scope from '=' to '@' because you passing string. and instead of scope.scopeAB to self.scopeAB

Comment: did my answer not explain the problem?  you just edited your question to ask exactly what I addressed.  Did you need further explanation of the changes I made in the working example?

Comment: you changed your code again to something that makes even less sense.  What is `arguments.scopeAB`? where would you expect that to be set?  I'm still unclear as to why my answer doesn't do what you are intending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some syntax errors which are causing your controller to not be initialized:

`<div controller="myCtrl">` should be `ng-controller` and `MyCtrl` to match up with your controller definition, i.e. `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">`

With those changes to the HTML, the following controller will properly set the values inside the directive:

```js
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('Controller\'s  function initializing some values on the Scope');
  $scope.scopeAB = 'Hello';
  $scope.scopeAC = 'World';
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jobmz0w/

Comment: I'm taking your corrections and re-evaluating my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: I missed the `$scope` vs `scope` in the answer body, but I had it correct in the fiddle.  I fixed it now.  Essentially, these are properties on the controller's `$scope` object.  The controller does not have access to the `scope` object inside the directive, and in fact it wouldn't make sense for it to, since the controller couldn't possibly know which copy of the directive to update.

Comment: note, if you want to use `this`, instead of `$scope`, that is possible as well, though it requires a few more changes.  using `this` in angular is commonly referred to as the "Controller as" syntax.

Comment: Your JSFiddle does pretty much exactly what I need. Now I'm trying to figure out what the difference between your stuff and my edited stuff is.

The main difference seems to be you are doing `$scope.scopeAC = 'World';` and I'm doing it without the `$`. What is the difference?

Comment: trying to explain would probably be better done in a chat session than done through comments;  we can use the official angularjs chat if you like? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63378/angularjs

Comment: So scope without the `$` is just a local variable within the controller? Doh!! Well that explains **a lot**.

Comment: it's not exactly that;  I would be very happy to explain it in a bit more detail if you jump in the chat.